# Get icon position by service

Tags: android

[image]

I want get app  position from service.
Just like pic，I want  get Client app or  tom talk tom app  center position
and their rect/

Any idea?

Thank you！

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to improve the quality of your question.

Comment: If I understood you question correctly, you want to change the layout of another app from yours, which is impossible.